# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: users, docker

I am getting this error after installing Docker on Ubuntu and running `docker version` or `sudo docker version`.

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket 
at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/
containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

I installed `docker` using the convenience script from [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can arise in two situations:

1. Running the convenience script without superuser mode.
2. Running the commands as a user which is not in the `docker` group.

Solutions:

1. **Quick fix:** Run the commands like `sudo docker version`. **Solution:** It is recommended to run the script with superuser privileges to avoid permission issues during usage:

   ```
   sudo sh get-docker.sh
   ```
2. Add the user to the docker group to avoid permission issues:

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG docker your-user
   ```

**Note:** Adding a user to the “docker” group grants them the ability to
run containers which can be used to obtain root privileges on the Docker host. Refer to [Docker Daemon Attack Surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) for more information.